# Python Shell or Bash: How to decrement a number in a string many times in a file

Tags: python, bash, shell

In the following code I want to decrement the number after `Vec2(` which is 11 in the first line below:

```
  new Point([84], '[',{ x: 49.22, y: 33.75 }, 4.28, 13.5, [new Vec2(11, 2)]),
  new Point([85], ']',    { x: 53.5, y: 33.75 }, 4.28, 13.5, [new Vec2(12, 2)]),
  new Point([87], '[',    { x: 57.78, y: 33.75 }, 6.42, 13.5, [new Vec2(13, 2), new Vec2(14, 2)])
```

Output expected:

```
  new Point([84], '[',{ x: 49.22, y: 33.75 }, 4.28, 13.5, [new Vec2(10, 2)]),
  new Point([85], ']',    { x: 53.5, y: 33.75 }, 4.28, 13.5, [new Vec2(11, 2)]),
  new Point([87], '[',    { x: 57.78, y: 33.75 }, 6.42, 13.5, [new Vec2(12, 2), new Vec2(13, 2)])
```

I have hundreds of lines like above, I want to script it in `python` `shell` or `bash`.

How can I do that?

Comment: What output do you expect for the given lines? What have you tried and how did it fail?

Comment: I just edited the question with the Output expected

Comment: You seem to mean you want to decrement it? Take a look at Python file i/o and regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with Python and regexes:

```
import re

def replacer(match):
    num = int(match.group(0))
    return str(num - 1)

regex = re.compile(r'(?<=Vec2\()\d+')

with open('path/to/input.ext') as f:
    content = f.read()
result = regex.sub(replacer, content)

with open('path/to/output.ext', 'w') as f:
    f.write(result)
```

The regex uses lookbehind, so only the number (`\d+`) is included in the resulting match.

All matches in file are replaced using a function which converts the match to an integer, decrements it and converts back to a string.

Answer (score 2):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -pe 's/Vec2\(\K([0-9]+)/$1-1/ge' -- file
```

- `\K` makes the regex engine "forget" the preceding characters, so only the substring matching the following regex is replaced
- `/e` evaluates the replacement as code

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is mighty crude, but for a one-off you can use `vi`.  Create a macro with

```
:map t /Vec2(/^Mww^X
```

Press the `Enter` key to end the macro.  Then just press `t` as many times as you need.  Or hold down the `t` key for a while.  Just be aware that it will cycle back to the top.

N.B.: The `^M` is a single character, which can go into the macro with `Ctrl-V Enter`.  For the `^X` you can just press `Ctrl-x`, but you need the `Ctrl-V` so that pressing the Enter key does not end the macro.